# Spring MVC and Websocket Exception using Sockjs with Stompjs

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

Hello i have an Spring MVC 4.0.4 project completely configured using annotations inside a Wildfly 8.1 Server, the only problem is when i use the following javascript code for initializing Sockjs using Stompjs i get an exception that i don't understand, for clarity this don't happened to when i used XML based config, i use the tutorial in this [link](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

**Javascript Code**

```
var socket = new SockJS('/frontend/track');
referencesServices.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
```

**Weboscket java config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(WebSocketConfig.class); 

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        LOGGER.debug("INIT WEBSOCKET END POINTS");
        registry.addEndpoint("/track").withSockJS();//.setDisconnectDelay(30000);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/updates");
//      registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

}
```

**Exception**

```
17:57:40,997 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-24) UT005023: Exception handling request to /frontend/track/info: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://localhost:8080/frontend/track/info; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://localhost:8080/frontend/track/info; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:91) [spring-websocket-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:164) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.getHeaders(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.getHeaders(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:303) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.getHeaders(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:303) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse$ServletResponseHttpHeaders.get(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:149) [spring-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.addCorsHeaders(AbstractSockJsService.java:366) [spring-websocket-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService$1.handle(AbstractSockJsService.java:421) [spring-websocket-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.handleRequest(AbstractSockJsService.java:290) [spring-websocket-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:88) [spring-websocket-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 75 more
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springmvcangular.backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVCAngularBackend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring MVC Angular Backend</name>
    <description>Backend para proyectos usango Spring MVC junto con Angular JS</description>
    <properties>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0-rc3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-rc3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Application Initializer**

```
public class BackendMongoWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    public static final String SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppMongoConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(
                SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
        servletContext.setInitParameter("log4jConfigLocation",
                "classpath:log4j.xml");
        servletContext.addListener(new Log4jConfigListener());

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurityFilterChain = servletContext
                .addFilter(BeanIds.SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN,
                        new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        springSecurityFilterChain.setAsyncSupported(true);
        springSecurityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] { AppMongoConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {MongoSecurityConfig.class, WebSocketConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
        //registration.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
        registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Now with the help of smoky finally the websocket works on wildfly 8, now the only problem is an exception throws when the sockjs is connecting:

**Weboscket sockjs error**

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/frontend/track/491/xe9k638d/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

**Server Exception**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://localhost:8080/frontend/track/491/xe9k638d/websocket; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: WebSocket handshake failure; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.undertow.servlet.websockets.ServletWebSocketHttpExchange.<init>(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:91) [spring-websocket-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: WebSocket handshake failure; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.undertow.servlet.websockets.ServletWebSocketHttpExchange.<init>(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.WebSocketTransportHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketTransportHandler.java:87) [spring-websocket-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.handleTransportRequest(TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:254) [spring-websocket-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.handleRequest(AbstractSockJsService.java:317) [spring-websocket-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:88) [spring-websocket-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.undertow.servlet.websockets.ServletWebSocketHttpExchange.<init>(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.UndertowRequestUpgradeStrategy.upgradeInternal(UndertowRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:90) [spring-websocket-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.upgrade(AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy.java:119) [spring-websocket-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler.doHandshake(DefaultHandshakeHandler.java:215) [spring-websocket-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.WebSocketTransportHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketTransportHandler.java:83) [spring-websocket-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 75 more
```

Comment: I've got the same issue actually. Just found it comes from `io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl` which use `io.undertow.util.HeaderMap`, return `null` and cause `NullPointerException`. This library is native to Wildfly. I've not yet found any solution tho.

Comment: so the solution will be change the server to tomcat 8 for example?

Comment: Actually, this is working with Glassfish 4. So I guess it's a bug w/ Wildfly. I think it can be bypassed by modifying `AbstractSockJsService` at line 366 w/ Spring 4.0.5. I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: what do you think if i change the undertown-servlet for another using maven and then exclude the module using `jboss-deployment-structure`? do you know what module i can exclude and what jars include in my pom?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, because a lot of things use this module (and specially the method `getHeaders(String name)` which is indirectly causing the issue) but you can try. I think it should be better to modify `DefaultSockJsService.addCorsHeaders(...)` from Spring Socket (inherited from `AbstractSockJsService`). Tell me if you find a solution, I'll also do if so.

Comment: The library used by Wildfly can be found here : `modules\system\layers\base\io\undertow\core\main`

Comment: Apparently, undertow 1.1.0.Beta3 should fix the issue. I'm going to try. Here's the repo http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.undertow/undertow-servlet/1.1.0.Beta3

Comment: @DiegoFernandoMurilloValenci could you open another question for your updated issue? This one has nothing to do with the previous and should be helpful to others. Ping me when this is done, I might be able to help you on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the op :

First, you need to use recent undertow libraries. There's 2 possibilities but I only tested the first one :

1. Update undertow libs in `modules\system\layers\base\io\undertow\` :

   I only updated `core` and `servlet` from 1.0.15.Final to 1.1.0.Beta3 then updated both `module.xml` to use the new files.
2. Use new undertow libs in your projet (w/ Maven for example) and disable the module using `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.

The XML should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="io.undertow.core" />
            <module name="io.undertow.servlet" />
        </exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Second, in `web.xml`, you need to add `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` to `DispatcherServlet` **and** filters (if used).

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying the second atemp but the same error, i'm using java config so i don't know where to set `async-support` to my filters, i use `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` for my web initializer (replace to `web.xml`) and in `customizeRegistration` method i use `setAsyncSupported(true)` but i don't know where to set async in my `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` (replace for  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>) so i think that without this no one of the two options works for me, i can see the undertow version chanage in my exception.

Comment: i add my Application Initializer code where i set the async support

Comment: i use the first option that you expose but my view resolver don't works anymore, maybe all my problems here is beacuse i use java config instead XML, i try my proyect in Glassfish and works like a charm, so for now i use glassfish, glad that this works for you.

Comment: I don't know how to do with a non-xml definition. I've set `async-support` as `filter` and `servlet`'s child in `web.xml`. There should have an alternative in java config. Actually, my first goal was to migrate from Glassfish to Wildfly due to future lack of support.

Comment: finally i got this to work in wildfly 8 with the first option, i think that i was replacing with beta1 and not beta3, that was the problem, now websocket works in my proyect, the only problem is an exception throwed when websocket start i will update my question for show it

Comment: Thanks a lot, approach 1 worked for me! Undertow was throwing exception when client was sending async requests, upgrading the lib helped

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it looks like this is a Wildfly issue (see [WFLY-3474 - NPE in HttpServletResponse.getHeaders](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3474)).

Upgrading to a recent Undertow version (1.1.0.Beta2 +) solves that specific Exception but creates a bigger problem, since Spring Framework websocket module does not yet support this beta version.

[SPR-11919](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11919) should address your first issue.

Follow [SPR-11914](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11914) for the upcoming undertow 1.1 support.

Comment: i will add a new question for this, now do you thing this will be solvet in the version 9 of wildfly and next version of spring? i'm using spring 4.0.5

Comment: I think the undertow fix will be shipped with Wildfly 9. In the meantime, you can use Spring Framework 4.0.6 as soon as it's out (in a few days) with a non-beta undertow version.

Comment: actually, never mind about adding another question - unless you think that Wildfly users often try to upgrade undertow to a beta version?

Comment: As mentioned by @BrianClozel, this is working w/ Spring Framework 4.0.6 and non-beta undertow version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that server and client can't communicate each other (the caused by error say : `Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://localhost:8080/frontend/track/info; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`).

I think it's because of the path for SockJS which is not the same in client and server. Indeed, the value of javascript sockJS is '/frontend/track' (`var socket = new SockJS('/frontend/track')`), whereas it's just '\track' in server side (`registry.addEndpoint("/track").withSockJS()`). If i have uderstood well the spring documentation, path declare in SockJS both in server and client (javascript) side should be the same, but i could make a mistake...

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the path is well, because if i change it the error will be 404 and not 500 like in my case, is an server error

Comment: Can you show us your XML code that you used before, with all config file, and the other java code class which set up the dispatcher and the listner plz